# Interface Contravariance in TypeScript

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, typescript

As an intellectual exercise, I thought I'd see how closely I could implement some of the .Net generics members in TypeScript (0.9.5), I've gotten as far as `List<T>` but not sure I can progress.

(I realise there are workarounds for this, but I'm specifically trying to use the same implementation as exists in .Net libs, mostly to try and get an idea of the limitations still present in TypeScript).

Anyway, ignoring the fact that I don't seem to be able to overload my constructors in any meaningful way, in the .Net source the constructor `List(IEnumerable<T> collection)` checks that the passed Enumerable is not null, and then contravariantly casts it to an ICollection using `ICollection<T> c = collection as ICollection<T>`.

In TypeScript I do this `var c: ICollection<T> = collection` (collection is an `IEnumerable<T>`), but get the following Error:

`Cannot convert 'IEnumerable<T>' to 'ICollection<T>': Type 'IEnumerable<T>' is missing property 'Add' from type 'ICollection<T>'`.

My current code is as follows:

```
export module System {

    export module Collections {

        export interface IEnumerator {
            MoveNext(): boolean;
            Reset(): void;
            Current(): any;
        }
        export interface IEnumerable {
            GetEnumerator(): IEnumerator;
        }
        export interface ICollection extends IEnumerable {
            CopyTo(array: any[], index: number): void;
            Count(): number;
            SyncRoot(): any;
            IsSynchronized(): boolean;
        }
        export interface IList extends ICollection {
            [index: number]: any;
            Add(value: any): number;
            Contains(value: any): boolean;
            Clear(): void;
            IsReadOnly: boolean;
            IsFixedSize: boolean;
            IndexOf(value: any): number;
            Insert(index: number, value: any): void;
            Remove(value: any): void;
            RemoveAt(index: number): void;
        }

        export module Generic {

            export interface IEnumerator<T> extends System.Collections.IEnumerator {
                Current(): T;
            }
            export interface IEnumerable<T> extends System.Collections.IEnumerable {
                GetEnumerator(): IEnumerator<T>;
            }
            export interface ICollection<T> extends IEnumerable<T> {
                Add(item: T): void;
                Clear(): void;
                Contains(item: T): boolean;
                CopyTo(array: T[], arrayIndex: number): void;
                Remove(item: T): boolean;
                Count(): number;
                IsReadOnly(); boolean;
            }
            export interface IList<T> extends ICollection<T> {
                IndexOf(item: T): number;
                Insert(index: number, item: T): void;
                RemoveAt(index: number): void;
                [index: number]: T;
            }
            export interface IReadOnlyCollection<T> extends IEnumerable<T> {
                Count(): number;
            }
            export interface IReadOnlyList<T> extends IReadOnlyCollection<T> {
                [index: number]: T;
            }

            export class List<T> implements IList<T>, System.Collections.IList, IReadOnlyList<T> {
                private _defaultCapacity: number = 4;

                private _items: T[];
                private _size: number;
                private _version: number;
                private _syncRoot: any;

                constructor(collection?: IEnumerable<T>, capacity?: number) {
                    // NOTE: Capacity will be ignored is Collection is not null
                    //       This is because we don't appear to be able to overload ctors in TypeScript yet!
                    if (collection == null) {
                        if (capacity == null) {
                            this._items = new Array<T>(0);
                        }
                        else {
                            this._items = new Array<T>(capacity);
                        }
                    } else {
                        var c: ICollection<T> = collection;

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Has anyone else tried co/contra-variance with interfaces? If so, how did you get on?

Thanks,

Comment: Maybe a cast: `var c: ICollection<T> = <ICollection<T>>collection ;`

Comment: Thanks WiredPrairie, doing a direct cast does appear to be valid!

Comment: Plug : @TomTregenna I do have a library for common data structures in TypeScript : https://github.com/basarat/typescript-collections

Comment: Yes, thanks basarat, I did see your excellent work before I started.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While TypeScript does not directly support co/contra-variance, you can just use a type assertion in this instance (which happens to look like a cast in other languages like C#):

```
var c: ICollection<T> = <ICollection<T>>collection;
```

TypeScript doesn't have a simple way of confirming that the type assertion operation was correct (like is the `collection` object actually an `ICollection<T>`), so you'll need to decide whether that's important to you.

And, if you want [another](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21384298/95190) idea to simplify the code a bit, you could use a default value for the `capacity` parameter:

```
constructor(collection?: IEnumerable<T>, capacity: Number = 0) {
    if (!collection) {
       this._items = new Array<T>(capacity);
    } else {
       var c: ICollection<T> = <ICollection<T>> collection;
    }
}
```

The TypeScript compiler will generate a check for the value that looks like this:

```
if (typeof capacity === "undefined") { capacity = 0; }
```

Answer (score 5):

You can suppress the warning using a type assertion in TypeScript:

```
var c: ICollection<T> = <ICollection<T>> collection;
```

Type assertions don't actually cast the value - at runtime none of these type annotations or assertions exist as they are all removed. The runtime value is entirely unaffected by a type assertion.

But this doesn't solve the problem that you won't have an `add` method.

Also, `null` is an unlikely value for your test here:

```
if (collection == null) {
```

`null` is usually only used for deliberately absent values, you are much more likely to encounter `undefined`, for example. You can test for both of these using the short hand:

```
if (!collection) {
```

I know that you are performing an intellectual activity, so this next comment absolutely doesn't apply - but for anyone else it is worth noting that recreating things like List and Collection method-for-method to replicate .NET misses the point that TypeScript (and JavaScript) is a different language. All arrays in your TypeScript program are generic, so you get little benefit from wrapping them in all these different ways - it all just becomes overhead. But as I mentioned, as an intellectual exercise this is interesting stuff.

Comment: Arguments *are* checked at compile time. If you passed `1`, that definitely wouldn't be compatible with the parameter's type annotation, which is `IEnumerable<T>`: `constructor(collection?: IEnumerable<T>, capacity?: number) {`

Comment: I know now what I tested -- my interface was empty -- so there was nothing to check. :)

Comment: Ha! I did that once too. Structural typing does have some things to watch out for :)

Comment: Thanks guys, attempting to copy the framework verbatim was a fun exercise, but ultimately I think all I've done is found a really good anti-pattern! Your point of undefined vs null was a silly mistake on my part indeed. When I got down as far as the Array object I decided to throw in the towel. There's so much going on in .Net's implementation that I felt like I was really doing JavaScript an injustice in even trying. Thanks again, and sorry if you've had loads of notifications of me editing and removing posts, etc. I'm still getting used to the Stack Overflow interface.

Comment: The predicate `collection == null` checks whether `collection` is either `null` or `undefined`. By contrast, `!collection` also matches `""` and `0`. The former is preferred.